# ¿Cómo puedo acceder a la última fila de una database de sqlite3 en python?

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite3

Pues eso, quiero poder acceder a la última fila de una database para después mostrar un mensaje que muestre los datos de esa útlima fila. ¡Alguien me podría decir como? Gracias.
Aquí teneis el código por si os ayuda:

```
def createDB():
    conn = sql.connect("usuario.db")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

    conn = sql.connect("usuario.db")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(
        """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS usuario(
            nombre text,
            curso text
            )"""
    )
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()


    nombre = user_name.get()
    curso = user_course.get()
    conn = sql.connect("usuario.db")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    instruccion = f"INSERT INTO usuario VALUES ('{nombre}', '{curso}')"
    cursor.execute(instruccion)
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: Hola, te sugiero que hagas es [tour] y leas [ask] y [example] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si no quieres recuperar todas las filas de la tabla puedes hacer una query que te devuelva la fila con el máximo `ROWID`:

```
def get_last():
    conn = sql.connect("usuario.db")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    res = cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE ROWID IN (SELECT max(ROWID) FROM usuario)')
    return res.fetchone()
```

Si te da lo mismo porque el rendimiento no se va a resentir puedes recuperar todas las filas y devolver la última:

```
def get_last():
    conn = sql.connect("usuario.db")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    res = cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM usuario')
    return res.fetchall()[-1]
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias César González! Me ha funcionado.